# Разбор Android-приложения

Tags: android

Не так давно я писал тестовое приложение на Kotlin. К сожалению от кода осталось только само рабочее приложение в Android, которое я могу запустить и использовать.

Вроде все изменения закидывал в Git, и как-то не проверял, добавился он или нет. Вообщем сейчас там находиться одна из ранних версий.

**Вопрос:** можно ли посмотреть код activity и классов, не имея apk-файла, а имея только уже установленное приложение в смартфоне. Для Java есть определенное приложение в Google Play, но для Kotlin я не находил.

Comment: А сам проект куда делся, может есть шанс достать его из бекапов системы? На крайняк APK у Вас всё же есть - он лежит в смартфоне по пути `/data/app/your.package.apk` (если установлен во внутреннюю память) или `/<какой-то_путь>/asec/your.package/pkg.apk`. Можете взять любой бэкапер приложений - он найдёт. Но свои исходники Вы из него не получите - только некое подобие. И я не знаю есть ли декомпилятор прямо в Котлин-код, возможно придётся декомпилировать в Java и потом в студии/идее конвертить в Котлин. Естественно код на выходе будет скорее всего не рабочий и придётся допиливать

Comment: @woesss проект делался на другом компьютере, которого сейчас нет

Comment: и да по пути android/data/your.package.apk моего приложения нет

Comment: Разве я этот путь указал? В файл-менеджере самого телефона Вы его скорее всего не сможете увидеть. Смотрите через https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer. Да, и на разных API и моделях пути могут несколько отличаться, но если приложение установлено и работает, то APK сто-процентно есть.

Comment: @woesss у меня нету такого инструмента по адресу View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer в android studio

Comment: Вы студию принципиально не обновляете? Ну поставьте с маркета какой-нибудь app-backup или супер-пупер файл-менеджер с такой функцией. Если есть рут, то включите и зайдите в корень файловой системы.

Comment: @woesss студия самая новая версии 3.2, а его оттуда убрали в другое место

Comment: @woesss Но я нашел